# Adding new line at the end of each line using Python

Tags: python

How can I preserve the file structure after substitution?

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

import os
import os.path
import sys
import fileinput

path = "C:\\Search_replace"  # Insert the path to the directory of interest

#os.path.exists(path)
#raise SystemExit

Abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
print(Abspath)
dirList = os.listdir(path)
print ('seaching in', os.path.abspath(path))
for fname in dirList:
    if fname.endswith('.txt') or fname.endswith('.srt'):
        #print fname
        full_path=Abspath + "\\" + fname
        print full_path
        for line in fileinput.FileInput(full_path, inplace=1):
            line = line.replace("þ", "t")
            line = line.replace("ª", "S")
            line = line.replace("º", "s")
            print line
print "done"
```

Answer (score 4):

The question is not great in the clarity department, but if you want Python to print stuff to standard out without a newline at the end you can use `sys.stdout.write()` instead of `print()`.

If you want to perform substitution and save it to a file, you can do what Senthil Kumaran suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `print line` in the fileinput line, do a `sys.stdout.write(line)` at the end. And don't use print something in the other places in the loop.

Instead of using fileinput for word replace, you also use this simple method for word substitution:

```
import shutil
o = open("outputfile","w") #open an outputfile for writing
with open("inputfile") as infile:
   for line in infile:
     line = line.replace("someword","newword")
     o.write(line + "\n")
o.close()
shutil.move("outputfile","inputfile")
```

Comment: The comma will only replace the newline with a space.

Comment: PS: [Trailing comma on print to suppress newline will not work in Python 3](http://www.ferg.org/projects/python_gotchas.html#table_of_contents_4). sys.stdout.write is best.

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate the lines of the file with

```
 for line in fileinput.FileInput(full_path,inplace=1)
```

the `line` will contain the line data *including the linefeed character* if this isn't the last line. So usually in this kind of pattern you will either want to strip the extra whitespace with

```
line = line.rstrip()
```

or print them out without appending your own linefeed (like `print` does) by using

```
sys.stdout.write(line)
```